# python pandas is giving a keyerror for a column I group by, even though a boolean expression shows that the column is part of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, keyerror

I cannot seem to print the following line: `summarydata["Name"].groupby(["Tag"]).size()`

without getting the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\rspatel\untitled0.py", line 76, in <module>
    print(summarydata["Name"].groupby(["Tag"]).size())

  File "C:\Users\rspatel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1720, in groupby
    return SeriesGroupBy(

  File "C:\Users\rspatel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 560, in __init__
    grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(

  File "C:\Users\rspatel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 811, in get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)

KeyError: 'Tag'
```

I have checked that Tag is included as a column in the summarydata dataframe by the following:

```
if 'Tag' in summarydata.columns:
    print("true")
else :
    print("false")
```

which prints out as true. Therefore I am not sure why a key error is being thrown when the column is in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to group by a key on the column itself.  Instead you want:

```py
summarydata["name"].groupby(summarydata["Tag"])
```

from the docs:

> by: (mapping, function, label, or list of labels)

> Used to determine the groups for the groupby. If by is a function, it’s called on each value of the object’s index. If a dict or Series is passed, the Series or dict VALUES will be used to determine the groups (the Series’ values are first aligned; see .align() method). If an ndarray is passed, the values are used as-is to determine the groups. A label or list of labels may be passed to group by the columns in self. Notice that a tuple is interpreted as a (single) key.

In other words you can pass it anything ;)  (This is why I don't like pandas...)

You can pass it:

- a fn, which is called on every value
- a dict(!) or series, which will be used to group (what you want)
- a numpy array (ditto)
- a label or list of labels, in which case it groups *by the column in the object in question*

But in your case, you've already selected the `name` column, so the `Tag` column no longer exists!  (Think about what `summarydata["name"]` returns.)

So if you want to group like that, you need to group *first*:

```py
summarydata.groupby("Tag")["name"]
```